# C# Expressions.How to get Sum (Amount) for last month?

Tags: c#, expression

I hava a Transaction datatable with "Amount" field.

I want to get Sum (Amount) for 7 days

How can I do it in C# expression?

Thank you

Comment: what exactly you are trying to say i m not getting.. ? plz more spec.

Comment: do you want to call store procedure from c# code ????

Comment: You need to provide the entire schema of the table in order to know what columns denote the dates within a month. Please update your question. Also, please specify what framework you are using to retrieve your information from the database in order to determine if the data is enumerable for Linq etc. Finally, state which version of c# .Net you are using as this dictates what solutions can be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your transaction table is called 'Transaction' and have a 'Date' field;

```
DateTime lastWeek = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7,0,0,0));
var amountSumLastWeek = (from t in Transaction
                        where t.Date >= lastWeek
                        select t.Amount).Sum();
```

**EDIT**: Of course const in C# means compile time constant and TimeSpan does not have optional parameters, so I have update the code